# Most efficient way to call multiple GUIs in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

My desire is to have a user select data, do a bunch of stuff to it, then to call a GUI someone else wrote (GUI3) and return varA, varB, and varC to the workspace.

Right now I have GUI1 which is just a button to load data and contains:

```
function varargout = GUI1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    varargout{1} = handles.varA;
    varargout{2} = handles.varB;
    varargout{3} = handles.varC;

    uiresume
    close

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.7';'*.m';'*.mat';'*.*'}, 'Select a .pfile');
    pfilepath=fullfile(pathname,filename);
    [handles.tempD,handles.tempE,handles.tempF] = functionF(pfilepath);

    guidata(hObject, handles);

    [varA,varB,varC]=GUI2(handles);
    handles.varA=varA;
    handles.varB=varB;
    handles.varC=varC;

    guidata(hObject,handles) ; 
    uiresume
```

GUI2 does most of the work:

```
function GUI2_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;

    handles.tempD = varargin{1}.tempD;
    handles.tempD = varargin{1}.tempE;

    %%% does things with tempD and tempE and displays things...

    guidata(hObject,handles)
    uiwait

    %%% other functions allow user to interact with data and create tempN 

function varargout = GUI1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    varargout{1} = handles.varA;
    varargout{2} = handles.varB;
    varargout{3} = handles.varC;

    uiresume


function btnReady_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)
    handles = guidata(hObject); 

    %%% does a bunch of stuff that eventually creates varA

    [varB,varC]=GUI3(handles.tempD,handles.tempE,handles.tempN)

    guidata(hObject, handles);
    uiresume
```

And GUI3 does a bunch of stuff internally and then displays some of the data.

Right now all the GUIs stay open until GUI3 is closed, at which point they all close and the variables go to the workspace. Ideally, I'd like to get the variables to the workspace as soon as they are calculated and let the user leave GUI2 and GUI3 open if they want. I'd also like GUI1 to close as soon as it's button is pressed but still let everything else run.

So my questions:
1) How do I get varargout to the workspace right away before the GUI is closed?
2) How do I close a figure for a GUI but leave it to call other functions and GUIS? 
3) Is there some more efficient way of combining these .m files so the data is passed more smoothly and there's less places for me to mess something up?

Also, right now it returns and error from GUI2's btnReady_Callback:
H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent.

I've spent so long trying to figure out the rules of this that I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely sure what you mean by "assign the values immediately to the workspace" but I'm assuming you're talking about not waiting until the function completely returns. You *could* use `assignin` to do this

```
assignin('base', 'varB', varB)
assignin('base', 'varC', varC)
```

But this is generally discouraged since it may overwrite user's variables that they have previously defined. Also there is no real benefit to this over waiting for the GUI to return since `uiwait` is going to block execution of anything in the command window until the GUI is closed anyhow.

About closing GUI windows, since you are using `uiwait` and `uiresume` to wait for the other GUIs to be closed, you can't really close the first two GUIs, but what you can easily do is set their `Visible` proeprty to `'off'` so they just simply aren't visible to the user anymore.

```
set(handles.hfig, 'Visible', 'off')
[varA,varB,varC] = GUI2(handles);
```

In general though, this seems a little complicated (especially for GUIDE-based GUIs) so if you give  us a little more information about what you're trying to do, we may be able to provide a more elegant solution. For example, it's not clear why `GUI1` is necessary at all.

I think what you *actually* need is a non-GUI function to coordinate the opening/closing of all of the other GUIs

Comment: Thank you for the insight. If I take out the uiwait and uiresume, would that break functionality (in GUI 2 I display images, let the user draw ROIS, and then do more calculations on a button press)?

GUI1 exists because when I started the project I didn't know enough about GUIS and could only build GUI2 to launch with the files already chosen. A non-GUI function to coordinate opening and closing of other GUIS would be perfect. Is there a post or tutorial you could recommend explaining how to do this?

Comment: OK! I could do (1) with assignin (this also helped: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7517-from-gui-to-workspace) as I don't care about overwriting user's variables (2) I removed the vargouts from GUI1_OutputFcn so it can be called without specifying output variable names now that GUI2 uses assignin, and I put delete(get(hObject, 'parent')); into GUI1 immediately after calling GUI2 so GUI1 closes. Yes!